# Rendering issues inside fixed divs with Safari Mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, webkit

If I set `position: fixed` to my div, the font text inside will be rendered thinner and no readable at all.

If the position is absolute, relative or static the font is rendered in the right way.

The problem occur with Safari for **iOS 6 only**. I got no issues with an iPad with **iOS 7**.

Any ideas or custom webkit property I can tweak with?

(i've already tried  `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%` with no results)

The problem occurs even with system fonts custom font.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

This is caused by the different way the browsers render fonts.